# How to get a Scrapy request to go to the next page?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I need to parse the country code of each comment in my [web page](https://feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.htm?productId=32911361727&ownerMemberId=206054366&companyId=&memberType=seller&startValidDate=) then store it in a json file, but I am having an issue when I try to turn to the next page.

I'm not sure whether I used the correct way to send the request.

Here's my code:

```
index = 1
def parse_fb(self, response):

    data = response.body
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

    with open(ArticlesSpider.pro_id+'.json', 'a+') as f:
        user_country = soup.find_all('div', class_='user-country')
        for i in range(len(user_country)):
            code = str(user_country[i])
            code = code.split('">')
            code = str(code[2])
            code = code.split('</b>')
            code = code[0]
            json.dump(code, f)
            print(code)
    request_url='https://feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.htm'
    data = {
            'ownerMemberId': '',
            'memberType':'seller',
            'productId': str(ArticlesSpider.pro_id),
            'companyId': '',
            'evaStarFilterValue': 'all Stars',
            'evaSortValue': 'sortdefault@feedback',
            'page': str(index),
            'currentPage': '',
            'startValidDate': '',
            'i18n': 'false',
            'withPictures': 'false',
            'withPersonalInfo': 'false',
            'withAdditionalFeedback': 'false',
            'onlyFromMyCountry': 'false',
            'version': 'evaNlpV1_2',
            'isOpened': 'true',
            'translate':  'Y',
            'jumpToTop':'false',
            '${csrfToken.parameterName}': '${csrfToken.token}',
            }
    index += 1
    yield scrapy.FormRequest(request_url,formdata=data,callback=self.parse_fb)
```

Comment: What is the problem you encountered and the specific error message? That would help people better understand the possible solution.

Comment: What is going on with your use of `requests`, plus `scrapy`, plus a ton of `string.split`?

Comment: I used split to get the country code and I know it's a stupid way but  it works. There's no error message but it just couldn't go on to the next page.

Comment: Hello! I know the post is very old, but is there any source where I can check the parameters values sent to the url? I want to know how to sort the reviews by the latest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need BeautifulSoup? All this is superfluous.
Here is the working code for your product:

```
import scrapy


class CodeInfo(scrapy.Item):
    code = scrapy.Field()


class feedback_aliexpress_com(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'feedback_aliexpress_com'
    domain = 'feedback.aliexpress.com'
    allowed_domains = ['feedback.aliexpress.com']
    start_urls = ['https://feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.htm?' +
                  'productId=32911361727&ownerMemberId=206054366&companyId=&memberType=seller&startValidDate=']
    url = 'https://feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.htm'

    page = 1

    def parse(self, response):
        code = CodeInfo()
        if response.css('.user-country'):
            for listing in response.css('.feedback-item'):
                code['code'] = listing.css('.user-country > b::text').extract_first()

                yield code
            self.page += 1
            self.url = 'https://feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.htm?productId=32911361727&ownerMemberId=206054366&page=' \
                       + str(self.page)
            yield response.follow(url=self.url, callback=self.parse)
```

A lot of excess))) I know))) check it out) did in a hurry

Comment: I am glad to help

Comment: using classes is also superfluous

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are changing `index`, but not using it: your `request_url` is the same during the process. If this bit is the one that you are expecting to change the page

```
yield scrapy.FormRequest(request_url,formdata=data,callback=self.parse_fb)
```

than you have to change `request_url` before calling that.

Comment: I assume index is defined at the module level (although it is not 100% clear from the code snippet), and that the increment will take place after the first request so that the callback from the first request will have index increased already from the previous run.